# How to display the clipboard copied text inside a toast

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-toast, clipboardmanager

I'm new to Android. I want to display the copied coupon code.

Here is code:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Code", artist.getCoupon_code());
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
Toast.makeText(mCtx, "coupon code: "+clip+" is copied" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

How to remove the red-underlined text and only display the coupon code i.e. green underlined text.

output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you want may be found in

```
clip.getItemAt(0).getText();
```

or

```
clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText();
```

or, because you are setting the clip right there, you can just use the value directly, in the string

```
artist.getCoupon_code()
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below should do the tric for you.

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
Toast.makeText(mCtx, "coupon code: "+item.getText()+" is copied" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Find more info about copying and pasting from the link below.

[Copy and Paste | Android developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste#java)